# Question about difference between two expressions

Tags: python

```
if any([x % 2 for x in result]): 
 print("good")
```

and

```
if any(x % 2 for x in result):
 print("good")
```

I'm studying Python, but not sure what is difference between two expressions shown above.

Does the first expression check each element in list?

I try to code myself, to solve this problem, but I don't get it why those two expressions are different and what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what's going on, let's run the following program:

```py
def test(i):
    print(i)
    if i == 5:
        return True
    return False

if any([test(i) for i in range(10)]):
    print("Done")

if any(test(i) for i in range(10)):
    print("Done")
```

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Done
0
1
2
3
4
5
Done
```

The first version creates a list using list comprehension, and after the entire list is created, it is then checked for `True`/`False` values. You can see the entire list being created, because all numbers up to `10` are printed.

However, in the second version, you'll see that the output only goes up to `5`. This is because the second is a *generator expression*, which the `any` function than evaluates one-by-one. For example, as soon as `i == 5`, the `any` function returns true and stops iterating the generator.

Let's replicate the `any` function in the same way it works in the second if-statement.

```
def any(gen):
    for i in gen:
        if i:
            return True
    return False
```

This is pretty similar to how the builtin `any` function works. It looks at each element, checks if it is `True`, and returns before the loop is completed if a `True` value is found. The reason generator expressions are more efficient is because values are being created one-by-one, rather than all at once with the list comprehension.

Comment: There's a lot more to cover regarding generators in Python, googling some helpful resources is a good way to start researching if you're interested

Answer (score 1):

Both *expressions* (these are not "functions") accomplish the same result.

The first example demonstrates a list comprehension. This loops over every value in `result` and generates a new list with the result of each value modulo two. The `any` function then loops over that to check if any of those values evaluate as true. This short-circuits as soon as it finds a true value.

The second uses a generator expression, and as such, does *not* generate an entirely new list. This is more efficient.

If the list created in the first is actually useful, it should be created *before* the conditional and then checked. Only in this scenario would the first example be more efficient.

```
lst = [x % 2 for x in result]

if any(lst): 
 print("good")

# Do something with lst
```